# Hibernate Search not indexing items from database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm trying to integrate Hibernate Search in my application.
Rough summary of what needs to be done:

- Spring Batch reads out an XML file and persists the objects to database. This is done with de JDBCBatchItemWriter. Not the HibernateItemWriter because of slow performance.
- After all items are inserted I would like to build the Hibernate Search/Lucene index.

The problem is in the last step. Nothing is being indexed.

The setup is as follows:

There is a JobListener where I index the data in my database like so:

```
Session session = sessionFactory
 .withOptions()
 .openSession();
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
try {
  fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But when I check my index with Luke I can't find any records in it.
I guess it is has something to do with transactions but I can't figure out how to make it work.

This my persistence configuration:

```
    @Bean
  public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("xxx.data.domain");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().putAll(jpaProperties());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

    return entityManagerFactoryBean.getObject();
  }


  @Bean
  public FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager(EntityManager entityManagerFactory) throws InterruptedException {
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManagerFactory);
    fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
    return fullTextEntityManager;
  }

  private Map<String, String> jpaProperties() {
    Map<String, String> jpaProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider", "filesystem");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.default.indexBase", "/tmp/lucene/indexes");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.search.indexing_strategy", "manual");
    return jpaProperties;
  }


  @Bean
  public SessionFactory sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws IOException {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("xxx.data.domain");
    localSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

    return localSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
  }
```

Entity to be indexed:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
@Indexed
public class EntryEntity {
  public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "SEQ_MY_TABLE";

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SEQUENCE_NAME)
  @SequenceGenerator(name = SEQUENCE_NAME, sequenceName = SEQUENCE_NAME, allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "ENTRY_ID")
  @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)
  private String entryIdentifier;

  @Column
  @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)
  private String value;

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: In addition to the post above: I can see that the SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor logs the following: 'Reindexed 1000 entities', so I assume that the indexing takes place but that it doesn't persist the indexed data.

Comment: If index updates are logged, the index should have been updated. Are you sure you are looking at the right location? How does your indexed entity look like? Any exceptions in the log file?

Comment: I've edited my post and added the entity that needs to be indexed. There's no exception in the logfile. The entity is indexed when I insert a new one through Hibernate. And yes, I'm sure I'm looking in the right location because I see the segments_1, segments.gen and write.lock files being created in the correct location. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you defining your Search properties in *jpaProperties* which is processed by the entity manager. When you call the mass indexer, however, you are using a plain *Session*. In this case the JPA properties will not be picked up. My guess is that there is some index directory created relative to where you start your JVM. 
Really you should always work with the `EntityManager`. There is also a `org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search` which allows you to get hold of a `FullTextEntityManager`.

Comment: Indeed, you're correct, I just found out that this was the issue! I've now instantiated the sessionFactory with the jpaProperties defined for the EntityManager